# efficiently working with sets in R

Tags: r, performance

## Background:

I am dealing with a combinatorial problem in R. For a given list of sets I need to generate all pairs per set without producing duplicates.

Example:

```
initial_list_of_sets <- list()
initial_list_of_sets[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)
initial_list_of_sets[[2]] <- c(2,3,4)
initial_list_of_sets[[3]] <- c(3,2)
initial_list_of_sets[[4]] <- c(5,6,7)
get_pairs(initial_list_of_sets) 
# should return (1 2),(1 3),(2 3),(2 4),(3 4),(5 6),(5 7),(6 7)
```

Please note that (3 2) is not included in the results, as it is mathematically equal to (2 3).

## My (working but inefficient) approach so far:

```
# checks if sets contain a_set
contains <- function(sets, a_set){
  for (existing in sets) {
    if (setequal(existing, a_set)) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

get_pairs <- function(from_sets){
  all_pairs <- list()
  for (a_set in from_sets) {
    # generate all pairs for current set
    pairs <- combn(x = a_set, m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
    for (pair in pairs) {
      # only add new pairs if they are not yet included in all_pairs
      if (!contains(all_pairs, pair)) {
        all_pairs <- c(all_pairs, list(pair))
      }
    }
  }
  return(all_pairs)
}
```

## My question:

As I am dealing with mathematical sets I can't use the `%in%` operator instead of my `contains` function, because then (2 3) and (3 2) would be different pairs. However it seems very inefficient to iterate over all existing sets in `contains`. Is there a better way to implement this function?

Comment: yes! I'll accept your answer. I would like to learn how R does it that fast behind the scenes...

Comment: In your loop, you're growing the list whenever there's a new value to add, which is generally not very efficient. I've also tried to use some already optimized functions in R (`lapply`, `unique`, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can rewrite your `get_pairs` function as something like the following:

```
myFun <- function(inlist) {
  unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(inlist, function(x) t(combn(sort(x), 2)))))
}
```

Here's a quick time comparison.

```
n <- 100
set.seed(1)

x <- sample(2:8, n, TRUE)
initial_list_of_sets <- lapply(x, function(y) sample(100, y))

system.time(get_pairs(initial_list_of_sets))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.964   0.000   1.959 
system.time(myFun(initial_list_of_sets))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.012   0.000   0.014
```

If needed, you can `split` the matrix by rows to get your list.

Eg:

```
myFun <- function(inlist) {
  temp <- unique(do.call(rbind, lapply(inlist, function(x) t(combn(sort(x), 2)))))
  lapply(1:nrow(temp), function(x) temp[x, ])
}
```